# rdrop 2, excel and shiny markdown

Tags: excel, shiny, dropbox

Is there any way to run the shiny app directly from dropbox? I have tried the package 'rdrop2' without success. The link to the package is here:

[rdrop2 at github](https://github.com/karthik/rdrop2)

However, when I follow the instructions in that link and use command:

```
drop_download('path/to/file/data.csv', dtoken = token.rds)
```

I get the following error message:

```
Error: Path exists and overwrite is FALSE
```

Does anyone know how to work around this error? Additionally, most of the data on dropbox is maintained in excel files. Is there any straight forward way to read an excel file from dropbox directly into R?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

First of all I think you need to pass the token itself rather than the `.rds` file:

```
token <- readRDS("token.rds")
```

As the error message states `data.csv` most likely exists in your working directory. You can check it with `file.exists("data.csv")`. If it returns `TRUE` your file already exists, so you have 3 options:

1. Use an `if` statement

Check with an if statement whether a file exists and only download if it doesn't exist:

```
if( !file.exists("data.csv")) {
  drop_download("data.csv", dtoken = token)
}
```

2. Set `overwrite = T`

If you think it's an updated version of the file you can set the `overwrite` argument to `TRUE`

```
drop_download("data.csv", dtoken = token, overwrite = T)
```

3. Only download if the dropbox version is newer:

   - If the file doesn't exist, download the file
   - If not, check whether the dropbox version has been updated.

Like this:

```
if( !file.exists("data.csv")) {
  drop_download("data.csv", dtoken = token)
} else {
  if (file.info("data.csv")$mtime < drop_get_metadata("data.csv")$client_modified) {
    drop_download("data.csv", dtoken = token) 
  }
}
```

Please keep in mind though that the timezone can be different on the dropbox metadata causing unexpected results.

### Edit:

If you want to read in a file from `dropbox` use `drop_read_csv`.

Here's a minimal shiny app that should work if you:

- Created `"token.rds"` using `drop_auth()` and `saveRDS`
- Have a file called `"data.csv"` uploaded to your root folder on *dropbox*.

Code:

```
library(shiny)

token <- readRDS("token.rds")
new_data <- drop_read_csv("data.csv")

ui <- fluidPage(
  tableOutput("table") 
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$table <- renderTable( {
    new_data
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I think I am fundamentally misunderstanding this. My working directory itself is on the dropbox folder on my computer and I am trying to read the file from there onto R. So yeah the file definitely exists in my working directory. I just want to have R read the file directly from dropbox when I deploy this as a shiny app.

Comment: Please check my edit to see if this is what you're looking for.